# Spring Kafka: Credential Rotation

Tags: spring-kafka, aiven

We are using Aiven as a Kafka as a Service provider, and they support credential rotation. E.g. every 24 hours.

So far, we have yet to find a way to create new consumers / producers in Spring Kafka when we need to rotate. Basically, a TopicAuthorizationException is thrown on `consumer.poll`.

What we need to do, is basically create a new consumer with a update truststore and keystore path.
Keystore and truststore is loaded from kubernetes secrets.

Anyone know how we can make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listener container will stop after any `AuthorizationException`.

You can add an `ApplicationListener` or `@EventListener` method to receive a `ListenerContainerStoppedEvent`.

You can either wait for all child containers to stop, or immediately stop the concurrent container; update the container's `containerProperties.kafkaConsumerProperties` with the new store locations and restart the container.

I don't currently see a good solution on the producer side; you would need to replace the producer factory bean or the `KafkaTemplate`(s) with new overrides for the store locations.

I'll have opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1641) to make it easier there.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into the suggestions you mentioned and thanks for opening a issue.

Comment: After checking a bit, how would this work in case of shutdown or other reasons to stop the concurrent container? They all publish an ConsumerStoppedEvent

Comment: We recently added a `reason` to the `ConsumerStoppedEvent`, but we don't currently have a reason for the auth failure ([I will add one now](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1643)). In the meantime, you could try to create a consumer after the event to see if you get an auth exception.